# Opencart Seo Url also work when some part of the Url is Removed

Tags: seo, opencart

I am working on a Open-cart website which has SEO URL's: Enabled and  it's  working fine,but when if a remove some URL parts between the slashes (/) it still shows the same page which was shown with the full URL ,what can be done to show 404 page in this scenario.

Comment: need some example / explanation..

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behaviour for Opencart and it's the way the url class is built.  I wrote a free extension a while back for 1.5.4 - 1.5.6 that will validate urls to make sure the product and/or category is at least valid according to the structure you have built.  You can download it here:

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=17659

Beyond that you'd need to decide exactly what is and isn't valid according to your preference and edit `catalog/controller/common/seo_url.php` to apply the rules as you see fit.  If there is a specific rule you want to implement you can describe it and I can make some suggestions if you're not sure how to make it work.  You should also mention which version you're using.